# Why is get-Property in domain class only usable with Set and findAll?

Tags: grails, dns

In `Domain` class `FooReward` I added a method

```
int getQuantity() {
  FooRewardAssignment.countByReward(this)
}
```

Usage in GSP should be `fooRewardInstance.quantity`, but that errors on startup (in bootstrap) with message that it has no setter method found.

If I change it to

```
Set<FooRewardAssignment> getListOfFoos() {
    FooRewardAssignment.findAllByReward(this)
}
```

and change the usage in GSP to be `badeRewardInstance.listOfFoos.size()`, it works and shows me how often a special `FooReward` is assigned.

Any idea what is wrong in version 1?

Comment: What is the detail of the error at bootstrap? It shouldn't error due to a gsp problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two workarounds for this problem:

1. Changing the return value to def:

   ```
   def getQuantity() {    
      FooRewardAssignment.countByReward(this) 
   }
   ```
2. Or by adding transients list:

   ```
   static transients = ['quantity'] 
   int getQuantity() {
      FooRewardAssignment.countByReward(this) 
   }
   ```

Sometimes GORM create column in tabel on the basis of setters and getters method inside domain class. And in this situation GORM want add column like 'quantity' but the error occur because GORM see only getter, and don't see setter. So we can say that we don't want create this column in database (static transients) or we can set return value as def - but don't ask me why 'def getters' are not taken into account by GORM ;)

Comment: 'def' getters are ignored because Hibernate needs to know the Java type to know what database type to use. So Grails ignores 'def' getters since def is an alias for Object. My preference is to strongly type it and add to transients since it's more self-documenting.